# Is Tools > Create GUID removed in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010, there was a Create GUID entry in the Tools menu. I used it all the time for SharePoint Development.

Has Tools > Create GUID been removed in Visual Studio 2012? I don't see it and resorted to Powershell [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()

Answer (score 69, accepted):

No it's there... at least it's available in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

If missing try adding it via Tools -> External Tools and add:

> %Installation Path%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe

EDIT: It's probably installed with Visual C++.

Comment: I'm running Premium, not Ultimate. Maybe that's the difference. I added it by External Tools. Thanks for the reminder. I found guidgen in a different path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

Comment: How is this not more popular?? Thank you!

Comment: Side-note to those running 64-bit VS. The VS installation is split between "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)". The Tools are located in the latter (x86) while my installation path is the former. I just used the browse button in the "External Tools" dialog and found it manually.

Comment: @Adil, thanks for this post! Worked like a charm. You saved me a lot of bumbling around! :)

Answer (score 45):

If you have Resharper installed you can just type `nguid` and hit Tab inside Visual Studio. You can even choose format you want.

Comment: thanks! it seems resharper has a lot of useful features that i don't know yet

Comment: @Zidad - generally people who code in VB.NET as it blows in this dev environment

Comment: @MattWilko Even more than without?